# How can I make two calls in one script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm beginner in jQuery/Ajax and I'm using Laravel 8. I have a form with a file input and three text input and I have a jQuery function in script and I need one more function in my script. For example: The function that I'm using in my script is cropping image (the function name is ijaboCropTool). When I crop and upload image my function(ijaboCropTool) is working but I'm display 'no file chosen' in screen but I want to submit all of inputs at the same time. How can I do that and how can I insert another a function? I can't insert `'async: false'`in my script because of my function.

**My script is:**

```
<script>

$('#file').ijaboCropTool({
          preview : '.image-previewer',
          setRatio:2,
          allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg','png'],
          buttonsText:['CROP','QUIT'],
          buttonsColor:['#30bf7d','#ee5155', 0],
          processUrl:'{{ route("testPost") }}',
          withCSRF:['_token','{{ csrf_token() }}'],
          onSuccess:function(message, element, status){
            alert('is working');
            
          },

          onError:function(message, element, status){         

            alert('error');
      }
   });

</script>
```

Comment: You can submit your form using ajax inside the `onSuccess` method.

Comment: [ijaboCropTool](https://github.com/Mbere250/ijaboCropTool) isn't up for the task in my opinion. 1. The `<input type='file'>` element stays with **No file chosen** even after successful file upload. 2.  The `onSuccess` event handler doesn't expose the `HTTP Response` object which holds the saved server filename. 3. It was unable to preview the cropped image at least based on my tests.  Please, consider switching to more stable libraries like [Cropper.js](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs)